# PDO lastInsertId() does not print any value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've done create method which should add new User object into database and on success it should assign id from the auto_increment field in the database.

Everything works except the fact that PDO `lastInsertId()` does not output any value.

Here is my code:

```
public function create() {
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare(
                'INSERT INTO users 
                (username, password, first_name, last_name) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute(
            [$this->username, $this->password, $this->first_name, $this->last_name]);

    if ($stmt) {
        echo $this->connect()->lastInsertId(); 
    }
}
```

Method `connects()` refers to method in Database class which returns PDO class object.

Comment: is there an AUTO_INCREMENT'ed column?

Comment: yes, I have column named id with AUTO_INCREMENT option selected for all my users.

Comment: Likely unrelated, but you should probably be checking the result of the call to `execute()` instead of the value `$stmt`.  `$stmt` _should_ always be a PDOStatement object.

Comment: @PatrickQ oh yes, I fixed that, but the main issue is still there :/

Comment: Do you have any trigger functions on insert into the users table?

Comment: If I correctly assume that `connect()` creates a new PDO object each time it is called, then each time a new connection is made and hence `lastInsertId()` will be empty as it returns the last inserted id of the »current« connection (cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).